# how to make widget disappear when overflow

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i have created spotify login UI by using align widget to make typing comfortable. but the image above doesn't disappear or get pushed like the align widget. is there a solution to remove the image or detect if an overflow occurs?

```
Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: [
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
              colors: [Color(0xff96979C), Color(0xff636669), Color(0xff25252D)],
              stops: [0.2, 0.5, 0.8]
          ),
        ),
      ),

      Positioned(
        top: medias.viewPadding.top + medias.size.height * 0.1,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage('assets/spotify.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
          ),
        ),
      ),

      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Container(
          height: medias.size.height * 0.35,
          child: Column(...),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

[image]

Comment: You like hide the logo/move up when keyboard is shown?

Comment: yes like that, is it still using the stack?

Answer (score 0):

Use column with the wrap of singleChildScrollView instead of the stack.

Something like this.

```
         SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                colors: [Color(0xff96979C), Color(0xff636669), Color(0xff25252D)],
                                stops: [0.2, 0.5, 0.8]
                            ),
                            ),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                                height: 200,
                                width: 200,
                                child: Image(
                                  image: AssetImage('assets/spotify.png'),
                                  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                height: medias.size.height * 0.35,
                                child: Column(...),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
```

Comment: but when typing widget username, password and buttons are not pushed up. I want to make it push up like in a gif but when I type the image is transparent